# RSS feed reader from the terminal in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, ubuntu-10.04, rss

Is there a way by which I can read RSS feeds from the terminal itself?

Something that would display the titles and a link to follow. Or maybe a software which works from within the terminal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A quick look at Synaptic shows a few candidates in the repositories:

- [nrss](http://www.codezen.org/nrss/) (dead, it suggests to use *Canto*)
- olive
- [Canto](https://codezen.org/canto-ng/)
- [Newsbeuter](https://github.com/akrennmair/newsbeuter)

Comment: Newsbeuter seems not user-friendly to config the first time. I get a better impression with canto.

Answer (score 10):

I *love* [Newsbeuter](http://www.newsbeuter.org/).
It's in most package repositories, has great documentation and it fits your needs.
Zed Shaw calls it ["the mutt of feed readers"](http://www.zedshaw.com/essays/i_want_the_mutt_of_feed_readers.html)

Comment: Newsbeuter is abandoned now, but newsboat has taken its place: https://newsboat.org/

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/akrennmair/newsbeuter has been forked as newsboat

Comment: *[Newsboat](https://newsboat.org/)*

Answer (score 2):

Check out [TermFeed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/TermFeed). It just came out :-)

All you need to do is:

```
$ pip install TermFeed
```

Then enjoy reading

```
$ feed
```

or

`$ feed <URL>`

Comment: i like it, but it seems not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out [Snownews](http://kiza.kcore.de/software/snownews/). Another alternative is Raggle (it has its own .org site which seems pretty unmaintained, but it works fine). Olive on *my* [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx) required 10.3 MB of dependencies!